# How do I use the bootstrap popover to display the content of a sibling or child element?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to get the bootstrap popover to display contextual content based on what element is being setup with popover.

Here's some example markup:

```
<div class="user">
    <img src="foo.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="userInfo">
    <p>He likes pie!</p>
</div>

<div class="user">
    <img src="bar.jpg" />
</div>
<div class="userInfo">
    <p>He likes cake!</p>
</div>
```

The script to setup the popover:

```
$('.user').popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'top',
    html: true,
    content: //What goes here?  I want to display the contents of the userInfo class
});
```

The expected result when I hover over the `user` class would be to show a popover displaying the content contained in the sibling or child `userInfo` class.

My markup can be flexible; I can move the `userInfo` class to be a child, sibling, parent, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yeah I would put the `.userInfo` inside of `.user`, then iterate over `$('.user')` and set the content for each `.user` separately (in your example you are setting the same content for all the popovers.

Example:

```
<div class="user">
  user 1
  <div class="userInfo">
    <p>He likes pie!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="user">
  user 2
  <div class="userInfo">
    <p>He likes cake!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.user').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    content: $this.find('.userInfo').html()  
  });
});
```

Here is a working jsfiddle (added some extra css):
http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/CTyyk/5/

Comment: Thanks!  I'm not sure why I didn't think to call `.each()`... that makes it easy as pie!

Answer (score 0):

You could leave his original markup and use this:

```
$('.user').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.popover({
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'right',
    html: true,
    content: $this.next().html()  
  });
});
```